# Problem in integrating Magento 2 with Klarna

Tags: magento, integration, klarna

I have installed Magento 2 on localhost and then I added Hyva theme.

Next step I wanted to do is install Klarna module.

As I see there are two Klarna modules on Marketplace:

- Klarna (with Klarna Payment and Klarna Checkout)
- Klarna Checkout

I installed first of them (Klarna). After I entered to admin I see configuration in Sales > Payment Methods.
I disabled Klarna Payment and enabled Klarna Checkout. I see on the internet that Klarna Checkout replaces default checkout on store.
But nothing happens. When I add something to cart and go to checkout I see the information that I don't have any checkout module and I must install Luma Checkout or React Checkout.

When I installed React Checkout I saw Klarna on payment method list on checkout (React Checkout).
But when I hit the order button I get en error in console and nothing happens on whole page.

Now I am testing this store on data from Klarnas sandbox.

I've tried to modify configuration.
I've installed it on fresh Magento.

I want to run Klarna Checkout on Magento 2.